# Circle CI cache mismatch

Tags: node.js, caching, circleci

I'm wondering why Circle Ci saves the cache in a different key than it restores from despite the config.yml that has the same keys.

```
 steps:
  - checkout
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
  - run: npm install
  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ~/usr/local/lib/node_modules
      key: node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
  - run: npm run linter
```

[image]

Is there something I should change in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this got fixed. I've done some changes.
First I've changed the `config.yml` so that restore & save cache come after each other.

```
steps:
  - checkout
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ~/usr/local/lib/node_modules
      key: node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
  - run: npm ci
```

Then I've switched it back.

```
steps:
  - checkout
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
  - run: npm ci
  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ~/usr/local/lib/node_modules
      key: node-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
```

This might have reset the keys somehow.

[image]

I've also replaced `npm install` with `npm ci`.

Comment: Don't you think that the really fix was the `npm ci`? Changing command orders does not make that sense to me.